# Need to check for empty string, visual basic

Tags: vb.net

Can someone help me to write a code that checks if string is empty and returns null if its true?

I have this now:

```
If(Not IsNothing(role.ROLE_DESC),role.ROLE_DESC.ToString(),Nothing)
```

But it only checks if role_desc is null, but I need to also check if its value is not an empty string and if so, then return null.

Comment: try using string.IsNullOrEmpty function

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1 check this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What taquion said, or `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.
Looks like:

```
If TypeOf role.ROLE_DESC Is String AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(role.ROLE_DESC) OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(role.ROLE_DESC) Then
    'It is empty or whitespace
Else
     'it isn't empty or whitespace
End If
```

Comment: Presumes that `role.ROLE_DESC` is a string, also, `IsNullOrEmpty` is a subset of `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` , so the first check is redundant

Comment: Almost there! Use `AndAlso` instead of splitting over two lines.

Comment: Ha, now that's just picky! You're not wrong though.